# Applying custom filter instead of the_content doesn't render embeds

Tags: filters, content, embed

In the theme I am using customizer to show content before (and after) posts, single post etc.

```
/**
Page Before Category
*/
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'content_before_category', array(
    'default'           => 0,
    'sanitize_callback' => 'theme_name_sanitize_integer',
) );
$wp_customize->add_control( 'content_before_category', array(
    'label'       => esc_html__( 'Page Before Category', 'theme_name' ),
    'description' => esc_html__( 'Content of the selected page will be shown on Blog Page before all posts.', 'theme_name' ),
    'type'        => 'dropdown-pages',
    'section'     => 'section_blog',
) );
```

And then in the `index.php` I used

```
$content_before_category = get_theme_mod( 'content_before_category', false );

if ( $content_before_category ) {
    $page_id = get_page( $content_before_category );
    echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $page_id->post_content ); // WPCS: xss ok.
}
```

But I've been told that using `the_content` filter directly is not good, since it could break plugins [as described here](http://themehybrid.com/weblog/how-to-apply-content-filters).

So I did the following:

In my `functions.php` I added

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'mytheme_content_filter' ) ) {
    /**
     * Default content filter
     *
     * @param  string $content Post content.
     * @return string          Post content.
     */
    function mytheme_content_filter( $content ) {
        return $content;
    }
}

/**
 * Adds custom filter that filters the content and is used instead of 'the_content' filter.
 */
add_filter( 'mytheme_content_filter', 'wptexturize' );
add_filter( 'mytheme_content_filter', 'convert_smilies' );
add_filter( 'mytheme_content_filter', 'convert_chars' );
add_filter( 'mytheme_content_filter', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'mytheme_content_filter', 'shortcode_unautop' );
add_filter( 'mytheme_content_filter', 'do_shortcode' );
```

And then the changed the filter to

```
$content_before_category = get_theme_mod( 'content_before_category', false );

if ( $content_before_category ) {
    $page_id = get_page( $content_before_category );
    echo apply_filters( 'mytheme_content_filter', $page_id->post_content ); // WPCS: xss ok.
}
```

Which works for everything except embedded content.

The youtube videos, twitter won't render as they normally do.

I tried searching for an embed filter but couldn't find one.

Any advice?

Comment: Applying `the_content` filter is not bad as long as you are explicit. Use it!

Comment: Explicit? Can you elaborate a bit? You mean what cybmeta mentioned in the answer below with the global `$post` content?

Comment: Explicit as in your `if` statement being true. Yes, his example is perfect imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`the_content` filter is as good as other filters are. The issue is that it is supposed to be run inside a loop with the glogal `$post` correctly set to current post in the loop. So, you could do something like this (not tested, just written here as example):

```
$content_before_category = get_theme_mod( 'content_before_category', false );

if ( $content_before_category ) {

    global $post;

    // get_page() is deprecated; use get_post() instead
    // $page_id = get_page( $content_before_category );
    $post = get_post( $content_before_category );

    // Setup global post data with our page
    setup_postdata( $post );

    // Output the content
    the_content();

    // Reset global post data
    wp_reset_postdata();

}
```

If you prefer to run your custom filters, you can. The problem you have with embedded content is that you have not run the auto embbed filter; just add it:

```
global $wp_embed;
add_filter( 'mytheme_content_filter', array( $wp_embed, 'autoembed') );
```

Comment: This does the trick! The `autoembed` one. Thanks! I think that's easier than defining the `$post` global and then resetting it everywhere I used `the_content` filter (there are a few more places I used it in). So this does it ^^